# Open conjugacy classes in a second countable profinite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a second countable profinite group, $g\in G$ and $g^G:=\{hgh^{-1}~|~h\in G\}$ the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$. Theorem 3.2 in Wesolek's [Conjugacy class conditions in locally compact second countable groups](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2016-144-01/S0002-9939-2015-12645-7/) gives a characterization of a profinite group having an open conjugacy class. For example, $g^G$ is open if and only if the Haar measure on $g^G$ is greater than $0$. In particular, if $g^G$ is open, then $g$ must has finite order in $G$, see Lemma 3.1 of the paper. I'm interested in the following case:

**Question:** Let $G$ be a second countable infinite profinite group, $g\in G$ of finite order such that the conjugacy class $g^G$ of $g$ generates $G$ as an abstract group. Is $g^G$ open in $G$?

Since infinite profinite group is uncountable, the set $g^G$ must be infinite. Moreover, $g^G$ and $G$ have the same cardinality by the question [Does a countable set generate a countable group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346244/does-a-countable-set-generate-a-countable-group?stw=2). In this sense, one can expect that the Haar measure on $g^G$ should be greater than $0$, and hence it should be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there exist profinite groups $G$ with a conjugacy class of empty interior and consisting of elements of finite order, generating $G$ as an abstract group.

Let $H$ be a nonabelian finite simple group, and $S$ a nontrivial conjugacy class in $H$. Consider $G=H^\mathbf{N}$ and $T=S^\mathbf{N}$. Then $T$ is a single conjugacy class in $G$ and has empty interior. To be done, it is enough to check that $T$ generates $G$.

This is equivalent to asking that $S^n=H$ for some $n$ (where $S^n$ is the set of products of *exactly* $n$ elements of $S$). I don't know if it's always true. However it is enough to show that it's true in a single case.

Indeed, using that for a prime $p$ in $4\mathbf{N}+1$, every nonzero element is a sum of two nonzero squares, we see that every upper or lower unipotent matrix in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ is product of two conjugates of the matrix $u=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, and hence that every element of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ is product of exactly 6 $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$-conjugates of $u$. (For other odd primes it still holds that every element is sum of three nonzero squares and hence every element of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ is product of exactly 9 $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$-conjugates of $u$.) Hence $H=\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ works.

[NB The proof also works, in the same way, for the product $\prod_n\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{F}_{p^n})$, which has the additional requirement of being topologically finitely generated. Note that in this case the element $u$ still has order $p$.]

---

Edit (given follow-up question in comments): for an odd prime $p$, $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ has finite Prüfer rank and is generated by the conjugacy class of the diagonal matrix $d$ given by the diagonal $(1,-1,-1)$.

Indeed, first of all, $\mathrm{SL}_n$ over a Euclidean domain is generated by elementary matrices. So it is enough to show that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & x & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is a product of conjugates of $d$. It is indeed the product $dd'$ where $d'=\begin{pmatrix}1 & x & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$. Now $d'$ is conjugate to $d$, namely $d'=udu^{-1}$ with $u=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -x/2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice counter example. It shows that a profinite group $G$ may have a conjugacy class of empty interior such that $G=<g^G>$ when $G$ has infinite rank. But perhaps the answer to question is yes under the assumption that $G$ has finite rank? For example, if $G$ is pronilpotent, then $G/\Phi(G)$ is abelian, where $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup, and $G$ must be cyclic in this case, which is a contradiction. In general, for any profinite group with finite rank, then $G$ contains a pronilpotent normal subgroup such that the corresponding quotient group is virtually solvable.

Comment: @stupidboy what is your definition of "rank" ?

Comment: For a topologically finitely genrated profinite group $ G $ its rank is defined to be the smallest integer $r$ such that every closed subgroup of $G$ can be topologically generated by $r$ elements. For example, any $p$ adic analytic group is a profinite group of finite rank.

Comment: @stupidboy thanks. I added another example that is indeed $p$-adic analytic.

Comment: On the subject of $S^n = G$: The sequence $|S^n|$ is increasing. Suppose $|S^{n+1}| = |S^n|$. Then $x S^n = S^{n+1}$ for all $x \in S$, so $x S^n = yS^n$ for all $x, y \in S$. It follows that $g S^n = S^n$ for all $g \in \langle S^{-1} S \rangle = G$, so $S^n = G$.

Comment: Moreover Thompson conjectured that there is always a conjugacy class $S$ such that $S^2 = G$.

Comment: At the final, why is the conjugacy class of the diagonal matrix $d$ not an open set?

Comment: @Nobody $d$ is the limit of the diagonal matrices $(s^2,-1/s,-1/s)$ when $s$ when $s\in\mathbf{Z}_p^\times$ tends to $1$. These matrices, for $s\neq 1$, are not conjugate to $d$ because their trace is $s^2-2/s$, which equals $-1$ only for at most 3 values of $s$.